# Whenever we edit any records,what is the last modified in trigger

Tags: limits

If we run data loader with batch size with different batch sizes,how does salesforce handle that behind the scene

If i have to load one million records with batch size of 200 how would salesforce handle that behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enough API calls that you wouldn't run out, you'd have to generate over 20 jobs *per record* before you risked running into limits. As you might imagine, most code won't run into that problem. Yes, you should avoid doing this intentionally, but in most cases, it won't usually reach any limits on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this would be a problem. My understanding is that Data Loader can do DML operations on up to 5,000,000 records.

Data Loader Guide:
http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/18/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf